# Direction of static friction between objects, rolling without slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> On a flat table, a uniform solid cylinder (C) with mass $m$ and radius $R$ lies on top of a long board (B) that also has mass $m$. There is sufficient friction between them to prevent slipping. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the table and the board is $μ$. The initial velocity of both objects is $V$ (to the right), which means that the cylinder is initially at rest with respect to the board. Describe how the cylinder moves.

I seem to lack the angle to handle this question, but here's my original attempt. Since B and C start at the same speed, and there is a static friction between, I imagine C will start to roll counterclockwise, meaning the friction from B on C is to the right. Accordingly, C slows down B with friction to the left, against the moving direction of B. Is my understanding correct?

My second thought: B will slow down because of the kinetic friction of the table. In response, C will roll forward (clockwise), which means the static friction from B to C is to the left. Accordingly, B gives C friction pointing to the right.

I feel my second analysis is correct, but not 100% sure.

P.S. I think I finally got it. Since C is moving to the right without slipping, it must be rotating clockwise, which means friction is to the left. Accordingly, C has a friction on B, pointing to the right. Problem solved.